# Modules missing after upgrading from PHP 5.5.9 to 5.6

Tags: php

I seem to be missing modules after upgrading from PHP 5.5.9 to 5.6.

```
$ php-config --extension-dir
/usr/lib/php5/20121212
$ ll /usr/lib/php5/20121212 | grep redis
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  255824 Mar  7  2014 redis.so
$ php -m | grep redis
$ sudo phpenmod redis
WARNING: Module redis ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available
WARNING: Module redis ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available
```

I also see a new directory for the module binaries since installing 5.6 which I don't know if it was there before:

```
/usr/lib/php/20131226/
```

I can see it has a load of *.so files there.

Also, seems 5.6 has it's own config dirs too (/etc/php/5.6/*). How should I resolve this? Do I need to install redis php again for this version of PHP?

Also, to get my current project working in the browser, it seems I can still switch apache modules between PHP 5.5.9 and 5.6 (`sudo a2dismod php5.6 && sudo a2enmod php5 && sudo service apache2 restart`) which allows me to access the previous version so my websites still have the modules they require. This isn't what I intended but as I at a slight loss how to fix 5.6 I'm doing this for now. Ideally we want to be on 5.6 permanently. Failing that I can revert back to 5.5.9 for apache and cli?

Comment: How'd you install PHP 5.6? Package manager?

Comment: Yes, I added the PHP repo for 5.6 `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`, then update and install `sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml`

Comment: OK, so do `sudo apt-get install php5.6-redis`. Repeat until it stops complaining about missing modules.